# Using Python (Flask) and PHP on apache2

Tags: php, python, apache, ubuntu, flask

I am running a page based on Flask and Apache2/MOD_Wsgi and am wanting to also deploy a page using PHP (a IDE called Codiad). Flask as my main page ( enjay.work ) and I want Codiad to run on enjay.work/codiad

Unfortunately I have the most basic understanding of Apache config and don't know at all how to find what I need.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName enjay.work
    DocumentRoot /home/nathan/www/enjay

WSGIDaemonProcess enjay user=nathan group=www-data threads=5 home=/home/nathan/www
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/nathan/www/enjay/enjay.wsgi
<Directory /Codiad>
    Options indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Directory />
    WSGIProcessGroup enjay
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On

    Require all granted
</Directory>

</virtualhost>
```

now when I navigate to enjay.work/Codiad I get a 404 page. for the php project I am adding to my site I followed these [directions](https://github.com/Codiad/Codiad/wiki/Quick-install-on-Ubuntu) (loosly)

I can get just the python to work, or just the PHP to work, when I combine the two Config files I get the Python page but the path that should return the PHP gives me a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the configuration for your PHP page to point directly at the project (in this case /home/nathan/www/enjay/Codiad) then above that configuration add an alias for the web address you want

```
Alias /Codiad "/home/nathan/www/enjay/Codiad"
<Directory /home/nathan/www/enjay/Codiad>
**Existing Config**
</Directory>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be like this.

```
<Directory /home/nathan/www/enjay>
    Options indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Doesn't setting 'DocumentRoot /home/nathan/www/enjay' make it so I can reference it relatively? [Source](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) @MEX

Comment: how to reference it relatively with '/' that means root dir.

Comment: Yes, and in my cofig I set the documentroot therefore I can reference it as /